# react-big-calendar resizable events

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I see that react-big-calendar recently added resizable events which I am trying to get working. Here is the code to their drag and drop example:

http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#dnd

click the Drag and Drop button => View example source code.

You can see in render the resizable prop and the onEventResize function. However, I do not see any resize in the example, how do you get resizable events to work.

I know this was a very recent release and that may be why the example is not updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you mouse over an event, when DND is enabled, drag handles will appear on the event. Where these drag handles display depends on the 'view' one is in (month, week, day, etc). A user can use the drag handle to change the duration of the event, or DND the entire event to another slot by dragging on the title of the event itself. When dropped, you must code the change of date/time into your code for the change to take effect, otherwise it'll just pop right back to where it was.